# sort function not toggling between ascending and descending

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I am currently working on a table, which sorts cat data in pure js and jQuery. I am almost finished. I can not figure out how to get my table headers to sort in ascending and descending order. I have tried various approaches including setting up boolean variables. Some something like:

```
//pseudo code
            var ascending;
            if ascending = true
            var sortedData = cats.sort(function(a,b){return (a.country < b.country) ? -1 : 1;});
            else ...
```

Currently my application sorts each column alphabetically but will not reverse sort. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=Windows-1252">

                </head>
                <body>
                    <div id="catTable"></div>
                    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
                    <script>


                function renderData(cats){
                        var output='<table id="indextable" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">';
                        output+="<thead>"
                        output+="<tr>";
                        output+="<th> HeadShot </th>";
                        output+="<th><button onclick='getSortedBreedData()'>Breed</button></th>";
                        output+="<th><button onclick='getSortedCountryData()'>Country</button></th>";
                        output+="<th><button onclick='getSortedCoffeeData()'>CoffeePreference</button></th>";
                        output+="</tr>";
                        output+="</thead>"

                    for (var i in cats) {
                        output+="<tbody>" 

                        output+="<tr>";
                        output+="<td><img src='" + cats[i].picture+"' alt='missing cat picture'></td>"
                        output+="<td>" + cats[i].breed + "</td>"
                        output+="<td>" + cats[i].country + "</td>"
                        output+="<td>" + cats[i].coffeePreference + "</td>"
                        output+="</tr>";
                        output+="</tbody>" 

                    }
                    output+="</table>";
                    document.getElementById("catTable").innerHTML=output;
                }            



                function getData(){       
                    $.getJSON('cats.json', function(cats) {
                        var cats = cats;
                        renderData(cats);    
                    });
                }

                function getSortedCountryData(){       
                    $.getJSON('cats.json', function(cats) {
                        var cats = cats;
                        sortData(cats,'country');    
                    });
                }    
                function getSortedBreedData(){       
                    $.getJSON('cats.json', function(cats) {
                        var cats = cats;
                        sortData(cats,'breed');    
                    });
                }    
                function getSortedCoffeeData(){       
                    $.getJSON('cats.json', function(cats) {
                        var cats = cats;
                        sortData(cats,'coffeePreference');    
                    });
                }

                function sortData(cats, element){
                    switch(element) {
                        case 'breed':
                            var sortedData = cats.sort(function(a,b){return (a.breed < b.breed) ? -1 : 1;});
                            renderData(cats);
                            break;
                        case 'country':
                            var sortedData = cats.sort(function(a,b){return (a.country < b.country) ? -1 : 1;});
                            renderData(cats);
                            break;
                        case 'coffeePreference':
                            var sortedData = cats.sort(function(a,b){return (a.coffeePreference < b.coffeePreference) ? -1 : 1;});
                            renderData(cats);
                        default:
                            renderData(cats);
                    }

                }




                getData();

                </script>
                </body>
                </html>
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reverse sort the code should be

```
 cats.sort(function(a,b){return (a.country < b.country) ? 1 : -1;});
```

Note that the 1 and -1 are reversed.

You can update the sortData function to receive additional parameter for sort direction.

```
function sortData(cats, element, direction)
```

and use

```
cats.sort(function(a,b){return (a.country < b.country) ? -1*direction : 1*direction;});
```

and use

```
sortData(cats, element, 1) or sortData(cats, element, -1)
```

for acending or decending

Comment: Thanks @Rejoy. The above changes with a little bit logic and my table headers are sorting and reverse sorting.